# Change/replace label text content by using css variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<label class="custom-label">arun</label> 

<style>
:root {--custom-text: "New Text"; /* Replace with your desired text */}

.custom-label::before {content: var(--custom-text);}

</style>
```

I have found that using before and after pseudo-elements, but I want to change the content ('arun') by using a CSS variable. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so. Using pseudo-elements you can add text, but you'd need to hide the existing text. Without another element around the existing text, any method used to hide the text would also affect the pseudo-element. But I'm happy to be wrong

Comment: Set `font-size: 0` for the label, and reset it for the pseudo element. (You won't be able to use a unit like `em` then, obviously, so if you need it to be somehow dynamic, you will have to make it work with `rem` then.)

Comment: CBroe's option seems ideal, but I don't think the text is selectable.

Comment: You have tagged JS - is a way forward involging JS acceptable?

Comment: Hi Haworth js not required . i wrongly tagged in js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `font-size: 0` for the label, and reset it for the pseudo element. (You won't be able to use a unit like `em` then, obviously, so if you need it to be somehow dynamic, you will have to make it work with `rem` then.)

```css
:root {--custom-text: "New Text"; /* Replace with your desired text */}

.custom-label { font-size: 0; }
.custom-label::before {font-size: 1rem; content: var(--custom-text);}
```

```html
<label class="custom-label">arun</label>
```

Comment: Hi CBroe  thanks for the answer . is there any  possible changing value arun without using pseudo element ::after and ::before ?

Comment: No, not really. (And something as important to usability/ accessibility as a `label`, should rather not have its text content manipulated via CSS in the first place. A work-around like this one might do in a pinch, when you absolutely can't get the actual text content properly changed on the HTML level ... but even then doing it via JavaScript instead, would probably still be better in terms of usability/ accessibility.)